# What is this mystery plant and should I pull it?

Tags: identification

These two plants appeared after a very wet winter. No flowers have ever appeared, but it looks like it is making a lot of big seed heads. I am thinking to pull it before it drops its seed. It is in full sun, and seems to be somewhat drought tolerant. Central Oregon. Photos taken a month ago, now seeds are bigger but no other real changes. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Agree E. lathyris - its pops up on its own, common name Caper spurge, where there's one, there'll be several next year, best pulled out, but wear gloves - the sap can be highly irritant to some people's skin.

Answer (score 10):

It seems [Euphorbia_lathyris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia_lathyris) . For sure it is an Euphorbia, with such inflorescence.

Comment: Thanks for the identification and link! It appears the plant is poisonous. Out it goes!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is Gopher Spurge. https://gobotany.newenglandwild.org/species/euphorbia/lathyris/